# Implicit declaration of function 'pool' is invalid in C99

Tags: c, xcode, c99, c11

The goal of this program is to store a large number of integers in an array as seen below. It uses a "pool" function to gather the integers with an index of 2 and it returns the "pool" to the main function. I tried compiling the code in Xcode 11 but there's this error "Implicit declaration of function 'pool' is invalid in C99" during the calling of the "pool" function in main. How do I fix this? How can I change the compiler on Xcode to the C11 standard?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 1000000000

int group[SIZE];

int main()
{
    pool();
    return 0;
}

int pool()
{
    for (int index = 2; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        group[index] = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C11 it's "even more invalid" than in C99 ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to put function prototype before the first call to the function

```
int pool(void);

int main() 
{
   pool();
   return 0;
}

int pool(void)
{
    for (int index = 2; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        group[index] = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```